# How to use GROUP_CONCAT with HAVING clause in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Joe | 0 |
| Joe | 1 |
| Marcus | 0 |
| John | 2 |
| John | 0 |

How can I use Pandas to have the same result as:

```sql
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(type)
FROM df
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| john | 0,1,2 |
| joe | 0,1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with something like:

```
out = (df
   .groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)['type']
   .agg(lambda s: ','.join(s.sort_values().astype(str)) if len(s)>1 else None)
   .dropna(subset='type')
)
```

Or:

```
out = (df
   .groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg(**{'type': ('type', lambda s: ','.join(s.sort_values().astype(str))),
           'count': ('type', 'count')
          })
   .loc[lambda d: d.pop('count').gt(1)]
)
```

Or:

```
out = (df
   .groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)['type']
   .agg(lambda s: ','.join(s.sort_values().astype(str)))
   .loc[lambda d: d['type'].str.contains(',')]
)
```

Output:

```
   name   type
0  John  0,1,2
1   Joe    0,1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do:

```
out = (df[df.duplicated('name', keep=False)].astype({'type': str}).sort_values('type')
          .groupby('name', sort=False, as_index=False)['type'].agg(','.join))
print(out)

# Output
   name   type
0   Joe    0,1
1  John  0,1,2
```